# TypeError to_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colaboratory to create a table to upload to Google BigQuery. My notebook receives the TypeError: to_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location' when attempting to upload data to BigQuery. The code is below with the error being thrown.

---

```
    from google.colab import files
    from google.colab import drive
    from google.colab import auth
    from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

    Drive already mounted at /content/gdrive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/gdrive", force_remount=True).

    import pandas as pd
    import io
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline

    ## Usage file
    df = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/My Drive/test.csv")
    df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Header1     3 non-null object
Header2     3 non-null object
    Header3    3 non-null object
Header4     3 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes

    df.to_gbq('table.new', 'tableproject-196326', if_exists='replace')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-efe83f801834> in <module>()
----> 1 df.to_gbq('table.new', 'tableproject-196326', if_exists='replace')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, verbose, private_key)
    160         auth_local_webserver=auth_local_webserver, table_schema=table_schema,
    161         location=location, progress_bar=progress_bar,
--> 162         credentials=credentials, verbose=verbose, private_key=private_key)

    TypeError: to_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'

    df.head()
```

This error just started to occur.

Any help on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Without code, we are just as clueless as you are

Comment: I just updated the question to include the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using pandas_gbq instead and import service_account from google.oauth2. The following code worked for me in Colaboratory.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas_gbq as gbq
gbq.to_gbq(df, 'test_dataset.test_table', 'add_project_id', if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the TypeError to_gbq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location' issue, but now I have another issue. to_gbq is not allowing quoted newlines. Do you know if there is a switch to enable this when using gbq.to_gbq?

Comment: Solved my second issue. I updated pandas_gbq to the current version and all is working now.

Comment: Solved my second issue. I updated pandas_gbq to the current version using !pip install pandas_gbq -u and all is working now.